# How to add different color backgrounds in a html if block?

Tags: html, css, flask

I am using flask to serve a html service. In this piece of code below:

```
{% if terms|length > 1 %}
        <div class="term">
        {% for term in terms %}
            {{ term }} &nbsp;&nbsp;
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

'terms' is originally a simple list of items **['a', 'b', 'c']**.

The current div class="term" tag add the same background color to each term as it iterates the values. Now , the terms become a list of tuple with values like the following:

```
('a': 1)
('b': 2)
('c': 3)
```

I want to add different colors to a, b, c based on its values, 1, 2,3. '1' gives one core, '2' gives another color and '3' another color too.

The current stylesheet has one entry:

```
div.term {
    background-color:mintcream;
}
```

How can I achieve this effect html and css?

EDIT: Per trimkas's suggestion, I added css definitions:

```
div.term.term-count-1 {
    background-color:green;
}
div.term.term-count-2 {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
div.term.term-count-3 {
    background-color:deepskyblue;
}
div.term.term-count-4 {
    background-color:blueviolet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the wrapping div inside the `{% for term in terms %}` loop, and add a class to the div that includes the current iteration number (index).

i.e.

```
{% if terms|length > 1 %}
    {% for term in terms %}
    <div class="term term-count-{{loop.index}}">
        {{ term }} &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Then reference in CSS in the way you need via `.term-count-0` `.term-count-1` and so on.

Comment: trimkas, please see my new css definitions above I edited. However the color doesn't change. The loop.index automatically maps to 0, 1, 2, ...?

Comment: @marlon your Css definitions are correct, but, please pay attention to the code I sent, you need to change the html as well (move the div inside the loop, and iterate the current index inside the class name)
Pay attention to the line 
`<div class="term term-count-{{loop.index}}">`
Then your CSS will be valid and it should work